# How to install eclim with brew or other package manager?

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew, youcompleteme, eclim

I am trying to install eclim to my system for code completion in vim. But as far as the [eclim website](http://eclim.org/index.html#how-do-i-get-install-it) has mentioned, the only installation method seems to be downloading the bin or source code to your system and executing the installation command manually. But I really hate installing stuff in this way as it pollutes your system directories. I tried to use brew but there doesn't seem to be a formula named "eclim". So is there really no way for me to install eclim with a package manager on mac?

Answer (score -1):

> I tried to use brew but there doesn't seem to be a formula named "eclim". So is there really no way for me to install eclim with a package manager on mac?

Write the missing formula.